# How Can I Close the Leftmost Window in Vim?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm trying to write a command that will close a tree-browser ([vim-tree](https://github.com/svenfuchs/vim-tree)) window and resize the other windows.

`,to` opens the window and adjusts the window size so that all open windows retain a normal size (using `:set columns+=30``CTRL-W =`).

`,tc` should close the tree window (full-length, far left) and resize the main window (`:set columns-=30`).

**How can I write a command that closes the leftmost window** so that I can type `,tc` to close the window and resize in one shot?

- I can navigate to it with `CTRL-W h`, but it is inelegant and potentially annoying (audible bell!) to use `10CTRL-W h` in the command.
- `:topleft c` unfortunately doesn't work.

Can you think of an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure that the bell is from the `10CTRL-W h` command? I just tried it and it doesn't generate a bell for me, while other commands (e.g.,`h` when the cursor is in column 1) do.

Comment: @garyjohn – I'll give it a try, but it's still inelegant! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the window really is full length at the far left, it will have window number 1, so a mapping like this should work:

```
:nmap ,tc :exe '1wincmd w' | close<CR>
```

This jumps to the first window, then closes it. The drawback is that the active window will become whatever was window number 2 (which becomes window number 1 when the original window number 1 is closed), rather than the last window you were in.

Unfortunately `:1wincmd c` does not close the first window, since <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> does not accept a count, so I cannot see a way to avoid first moving to the window you want to close.

***2017 Edit:*** Since I wrote this answer, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> does accept a count in newer versions of Vim, so the answer is just to use `:1wincmd c` and it will not switch the cursor away from your active window:

```
:nmap ,tc :1wincmd c<CR>
```